# Can't get ubuntu on new laptop!

Tags: boot-failure, windows-8

I just got a new laptop: the Asus VivoBook X2O2E, and for some reason, ubuntu's (12.10) not working. Whenever I install it, I choose "reboot now", and then it shows an error: cannot load windows and unknown program; missing a required file. After four tries, I gave up. However, my technological life requires ubuntu, so I seek your help.

Thanks,
rsinghal

Comment: You installed Linux over Windows 7 didn't you...? If you can answer that for me then I can tell you where to go from there.

Comment: How did you install, using Wubi or through a liveUSB or liveDVD?

Comment: To Cecel: I used Winsows 8 consumer preview.
To To Do: Wubi

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)? It may help.

Comment: to 0x4a6f4672: Well, the problem is, I don't have a disk drive in my laptop.